# You Force Heaven to be Ecstasy

Tags: password

You are Agent X, an enterprising NSA analyst who's been assigned the task of spying on Bill Krill, a US citizen suspected of unpatriotic opposition to warrantless NSA spying on American citizens.

By remotely activating Bill's webcam, you were able to spy out Bill's password reminder sheet on his physical desktop. Unfortunately, Bill appears to have only written down *reminders* rather than actual passwords.

> 1. Foodie Message Board Password: *You force heaven to be ecstasy.*
> 2. Library Password: *Am I too wise for you?*
> 3. Online Gambling Password: *I foresee an empty success.*
> 4. soopershoeshopper.com Password: *Knot 'em, or else he's won.*
> 5. Daredevil Message Board Password: *I once ate a hat for cash.*
>
> **Bill to self:** All of your passwords are 8 characters or less, and all of them use your usual convention.

Can you figure our Bill's "usual convention" as well as his 5 passwords, thus helping to make the world a safer place for citizens like Bill?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answers are:

> 1. u472bxtc
>  2. mi2yy4u
>  3. i4cnmt6s
>  4. 0mrlcc1
>  5. i118a^4$

Method:

> Bill's convention is to form sentences from a sequence of characters that sound like words.